# How to translate "Include file(s) as attachment(s). Missing files will not be attached."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Is it correct translation?
Datei(en) als Anhang(e) hinzufügen. Fehlende Dateien werden nicht angehängt.

Comment: The second version is "Datei(en) als Anhang(Anhänge) einschließen. Fehlende Dateien werden nicht angehängt."

Comment: Thats somehow nonsense both in German and English. (The "missing Files won't be attached" part)

Comment: It makes sense for a program where some files are on a server, but if you don't download them, they are not on your PC's disk, but you include not only a file, but also information about it to an email. So there is a situation that you include a file and information about it to an email, but this file isn't on a disk, but information about its existing automatically will be added to an email. )))

Comment: Need only correct translation into German) It makes a nonsense to you without context.

Comment: This question seems to be off topic for the site since it asks for proofreading. If you have specific issues with the meanings of words or the grammar then please include them in the question. I'm still a bit confused about the missing files; this needs to be clarified if you want the best translation since the context and intended meaning are needed, not just words.

Comment: @Andriy: Correct translation will depend on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nein.

> Datei(en) als Anhang(e) hinzufügen. Fehlende Dateien werden nicht angehängt.

Die Mehrzahl von Anhang ist nicht Anhange, sondern Anhänge. Der Anhang bei einer Email kann aber als **ein** Ding betrachtet werden, das aus mehreren Dateien besteht, so dass man der komplizierten Darstellung der Varianten sich leicht entziehen kann:

> Datei(en) als Anhang hinzufügen. Fehlende Dateien werden nicht angehängt.

In welchem Kontext fehlende Dateien angehängt werden könnten, so dass der 2. Hinweis Sinn ergibt, ist nicht Gegenstand dieser Antwort.

Comment: Danke. Thank you.